# where can I find refunds in cash and refunds in store credit in the database?

Tags: database, magento2.4, creditmemo, store-credit, rma

I'm looking to compare refunds that have been paid in cash vs by store credit in the database, but I cannot find any info myself.

Answer (score 0):

Customer's store credit can use Credit Memo and Customer Balance tables:

Credit memo:

```
select * from sales_creditmemo;
select * from sales_creditmemo_item;
select * from sales_creditmemo_grid;
select * from sales_creditmemo_comment;
```

In regards to customer balance:

```
select * from magento_customerbalance;
select * from magento_customerbalance_history;
```

Please note the customer balance tables keep tabs on records added via Credit Memo as well as manual amounts added directly to the customer via Magento Admin.